# how to join thread working with another one

Tags: winforms, multithreading

I have a thread changes in a control in a form in a windows forms application,

I implement the invoke method for prevent threading cross access,

but when I close the form, the second thread still work and try to access to the control and throw an object reference not set to an instance of object exception

how can I assure preventing second thread working if the first one is not alive

without manual checking recommended

thanks in advance

Comment: Need more information on how you are creating the thread, such as using a Timer, BackgroundWorker, and so on. Also, how is the form closed, by the user, through code?

Comment: Have you got a check, as in `if object is not nothing then invoke`.

Comment: Do you want this second thread to continue execution after the form closes, or do you want this thread stopped when form closes?

Comment: Thanks AMissico and Justin Ethier for your answers

I'm using the Thread class without BackgroundWorker timer,

and I don't want to continue executing after user (not programmatically), close the program,

I just want to close without exceptions

thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to closing the form, you could notify the thread that it is about to be cancelled. For example, if you are using `BackgroundWorker` for your thread you could call the [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) method.

**Update**

To support this when using the `Thread` class you can either call [Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=VS.100).aspx) - which is not recommended - or you could use a shared variable. Basically you can have a boolean `isCancelled` that the thread periodically checks - and if it is false the thread returns. Then you can set this boolean from the UI thread to signal the background thread to stop. You would also need to make sure you properly `lock` the boolean before accessing it from either thread.

There are other techniques you can use as well - if you post your thread code we could help you more with that.